# Dynamic Where in Linq to SQL

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic, where-clause

How would I get something like this to work so that I can dynamically alter the where-clause in this linq to sql query?

```
Dim AccountID = 1234

Dim AccountList

Select Case Types
    Case 1
        AccountList = (from a in dc.Accounts where a.ID = AccountID)
    Case 2
        AccountList = (from a in dc.Accounts where a.ID = AccountID And a.ParentID = AccountID)
    Case Else
        AccountList = (from a in dc.Accounts)
End Select

Return From p in dc.Products where AccountList.Contains(p.Order.Transaction.AccountID)
```

With the above code I get this error:

***Late binding operations cannot be converted to an expression tree***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've either not got Option Strict on. Put it on, and specify the type of `AccountList` as `IQueryable(Of Account)`. Then you won't be using late binding, and all should be well.

Comment: The AccountList is just a list of strings actually so making it IQueryable(of String) did the trick - thanks!